# Excel Mac - create graphs with two columns with values for x- and y-axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2019

In my Excel-file, I have four columns with information that I want to graph:
[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzDdu.png)

I want to graph this information as follows: the values of t, time, should be the x-axis and the values for A, B and C are the corresponding y-values. I have Excel for Mac, but I can't get this to work. I already searched a lot on the internet, but to no avail.
I also need a way to plot e.g. two columns, say that the column with B represents the x-values and the column with A the y-values.

All the points should be connected with each other, like done on the below image.

So how do I create graphs, where I have two (or more) columns for the x- and the y-axis?

Thanks a lot in advance!

[image: Graph styling of Excel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the values of t, time, should be the x-axis and the values for A, B
>   and C are the corresponding y-values

The Scatter with Lines could meet your needs. Select the data of Time and columns with A, B and C > Insert Scatter, such as the Scatter with Straight Lines.

[image]

When you need to change the data range for X-axis values and Y-axis values, please right click the chart > Select Data > Select the series that you need to modify, then choose

[image]

Comment: Hi @Emily thanks for answering it. I'm going to test it tomorrow and let you know if I get it working!

Comment: I just tested it and it works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**For your first problem (to plot multiple 'y' values), do the following:**

- Select all the data that you've arranged like this:

[image]

- After that, go to `Insert>Scatter` and choose a graph type:

[image]

- You will have the result on your screen. See this:

[image]

**For your second problem (to plot 'B' as X and 'A' as Y):**

- *Without selecting* any data, go to `insert>scatter` and choose a graph type. This will bring a blank graph canvas on your screen.
- Right click on the blank canvas and choose `Select Data`:

[image]

- On the next screen that appears, click `Add`.
- On the "Edit Series" menu that pops up, enter a series name. I have entered **A-B** here.
- In Series X values, put `=Sheet1!$C$2:$C$11` where `$C$2` is the first numeric cell of the data column **B** (which you want as X axis) and `$C$11` last in my case. You have to adjust these values in your case. For example, if `C20` is your last numeric cell in data column **B** and `C2` first, change the given formula to: `=Sheet1!$C$2:$C$20` where `Sheet1` refers to the sheet name.
- Similarly, put in the values of Series Y, as shown below:

[image]

- Press 'OK' and then again 'OK' on the menu that appear. That's it. You'll have your desired graph right there.

I hope this helps. Do tell how it does :)

Comment: Hi @Sanu_012 thanks for answering. I'm going to test it tomorrow and let you know if I get it working!

Comment: I tested it and it works! Thanks for the help. I upvoted the answer, but it does not display it because I don't have enough reputation yet.. I marked the first answer as correct, because it came in first as far as I can see (and it was for Mac, although your answer also worked correct). If I have more than 15 reputation, I'll certainly come back and upvote the answer!

Comment: Okay mate, no worries. Just give one after having enough reputation.